# RFuture to completable future

Tags: redisson

I am porting a implementation from Caffeine to redisson to use redis caching. I need to return to keep exisitng interface for a get as CompletableFuture<();

Since RMapCache.getAsync(key).thenApply() returns CompletionStage it breaks the CompletableFuture return interface. How to transform?

Comment: [CompletionStage.toCompletableFuture()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#toCompletableFuture())

Comment: Thanks @BenManes I had figured it myself but thanks for staying active and helping within the caffeine community!